# Create a Multidimensional array where row = month and column = date

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array where the row corresponds to the month that a user inputs and the column corresponds to the date that the user inputs but it doesn't look like I"m doing it properly because I keep receiving an error that says "5" is undefined. How do I populate a multidimensional array like this?

```
var calendar = new Array (20);
calendar [9][5] = "Labor Day";
```

And then trying to loop through it like this to see if the user input matches where day and month are already defined with the user input

```
for (var i = 0; i < calendar.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < calendar.length; j++) {
        if (day==i && month ==j){
            document.write(calendar[i][j]);
        }
        else{
            document.write("This is not a holiday");
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: `var calendar = new Array (20);` 20 monthes per year ??

Answer (score 0):

`calendar` isn't a single, multidimensional array, but rather an Array-of-Arrays.

To populate it, you'll have to initialize each level within that.

```
var calendar = new Array(20);
calendar[9] = new Array();
calendar[9][5] = "Labor Day";
```

Without the 2nd initialization, the error you're getting is most likely:

> Cannot set property '5' of undefined

This doesn't mean that `[5]` is undefined, but that what's to the left of it is:

```
var calendar = new Array(20);
console.log(calendar[9]); // undefined
```

In that case, `calendar[9][5] = "Labor Day";` is evaluated to `undefined[5] = "Labor Day";`, which isn't permitted.

---

The arrays are also [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) with elements missing between `0` and `length`. So, to iterate through them, you'll need do so conditionally:

```
for (var i = 0; i < calendar.length; i++) {
    if (!calendar[i]) continue; // no element, try the next

    for (var j = 0; j < calendar[i].length; j++) {
        if (calendar[i][j]) {
            document.write(calendar[i][j]);
        } else {
            document.write("This is not a holiday");
        }
    }
}
```

Though, if you're starting with `month` and `day`, since the Arrays are indexed by those values, you can use these in place of `i` and `j` and test for a value without needing to iterate.

```
if (calendar[month] && calendar[month][day]) {
     document.write(calendar[month][day]);
} else {
     document.write("This is not a holiday");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would avoid using the `new` key word. I would declare the array this way -

`var calendar = [];`

The second thing you need to remember is that a 2d array is an array of arrays. 
So what you should do now, is initiliase the array.

```
for (let i=1; i<=12; i++) { //each year has 12 months
    for (let j=1; j<=30; j++) { // suppose each month has 30 days. 
    calendar.push([i,j]);
 }
}
```

And now you got yourself an array of 12 months with 30 days per month. You can always modify the number of days at certain month.

**EDIT**

After having the calendar array, you can create an object that will hold the array parameters as keys and strings as values.
Just create an array:
`var calObject = {};`

And now set the array parameters as keys:

```
for (c in calendar) {
  calObject[calendar[c]] = '';
}
```

Now, you can give each day a name

`calObject['5,4'] = 'Labor Day'`

And voila!!

Notice, that the parameters inside the brackets are strings.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now do you know how I can populate the array with specific dates having specific values?

Comment: Now you have an array of an arrays of Numbers. You can modify it now that it can have strings instead of Numbers. Console.log your array, and see how you can change the values

Comment: @anon, I have added an edit with the things that you need. Let me know if it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript ES6...

```
const calendar = [...Array(12)].map(month => Array(31));
calendar[9][5] = 'Labor Day';
console.log(calendar[9][5]); // -> Labor Day
```